# PhoneGap - Cordova build android faild

Tags: android, cordova

I'm new in phonegap. I have this problem when I try to build with cordova :

> sudo cordova build android

Here is the log :

```
Running command: /home/paul/Documents/Projets/tozer0-app/platforms/android/cordova/build 
[Error: Failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/paul/Documents/Projets/tozer0-app/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /home/paul/Documents/Projets/tozer0-app/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score -1):

Just add the JAVA_HOME , ANDROID_HOME and ANT_HOME to path and point out the corresponding bin directory as:
For android studio

add this into your ~/.bashrc file:

1. export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/android/SDK
2. export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin

you can do the same for Ant.
For java jdk

add this into your /etc/profile file:

1. JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk
2. JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
3. PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
4. export JAVA_HOME
5. export JRE_HOME
6. export PATH

Now in your terminal, type echo $PATH and make sure all the environment variables are added to the PATH!